# Seeking Windows hardware encryption card for drive encryption

Tags: windows, encryption, nas, home-server, accelerator

I am seeking a hardware encryption card for accelerating drive encryption on an older system that I am trying to repurpose as a NAS.

I have a dual-processor AMD Athlon MP 2800+ system with a 12-port 3Ware 9550SX PCI-X SATA-II RAID card. I am eventually going to have 12 drives in 4 × 3-drive SATA backplanes that take up 2 × 5¼″ bays apiece - the case has 9 standard bays. Actual system drive (O/S) will be a small solid-state drive that plugs directly into the IDE ports (not worried about performance there), but the 12 drives will be 2-4Gb traditional hard drives (size dependent on cost at time of purchase).

I am looking to encrypt the entire RAID-5 system (each 3-drive array) and I am limited to either WHS 2003 (the platform is a 32-bit system, after all) or [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/). I know about the Encrypting File System, but I want something under my own control, and I feel that TrueCrypt is the best option. Besides, I want to chain multiple encryption protocols, such as AES-TwoFish-Serpent, and this represents some pretty heavy lifting for an older system to do.

I have a spare PCI-X slot into which I can add another card. I am worried that the system will get bogged down if the processors themselves handle the encryption/decryption, and so I am seeking a PCI-X encryption accelerator card to offload the heavy lifting onto. So far I have found bupkis. Nada. Nothing. At least, nothing still for sale and in production.

Even other cards like this [Cisco Accelerator card](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/250894414686) seem to fit the bill, but likely do not come with Windows drivers and are meant for specialty uses. Heck, the card even does the encryption protocols I want to use, but the card itself seems to be limited to VPN use.

I am seeking suggestions from the community -- what are my options on PCI-X encryption accelerator cards that are still in production and available for sale?

Please keep in mind -- PCI or PCI-X **ONLY**. No PCIe, as the system has ZERO PCIe slots.

Comment: TrueCrypt does not even support TPM, so I guess you will have to use the software that comes with the card. Theoretically if you use a hardware card, all disk access will go through it. The bandwidth and latency requirement seems to be impossible to satisfy.

Comment: ...and if you do the encryption with a hardware card, buy a spare too - nothing worse than having the main card die and nothing to replace it and get you back onto your array. Mind you, you will have backups...won't you ;-)

Comment: Truecrypt DOES use hardware acceleration, but [only processor-based acceleration](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=hardware-acceleration).

Comment: [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/) is looking more and more attractive…

Comment: Just bumping this so that fresh eyes might be able to help…